# How to enable/disable image button using id in jquery?

Tags: jquery

In my code i have one form its have one text field and submit button(it is image with hyperlink).

```
 <input type="text" name="ticketcom[]" id="ticketcom_'.$aff_rep_id.'" class="form_textfeild" style="width:100px;" value="'.$result_bt_value.'"/>
```

and submit button

```
<div style="margin-left:190px;"><a href="#" class="close" id="submitcommision"><img src="__SITE_URL__/images/seller/save_btn.png" width="75" height="32" border="0" alt="dd"/></a></div>
```

when text box is empty the submit not need to work otherwise proceed to next step its disable the button when text box is empty otherwise enable the button for this i am written code like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitcommision").click(function() {
    var num11 = $("#ticketcom_$aff_rep_id").val();
    if(num11=='')
    {
    $('#submitcommision').attr('disabled',true);
    }
    });
```

but it is not working properly how can i do it in jquery help me.

Comment: Use `prop('disabled', true)` or `attr('disabled', 'disabled')`

Answer (score 0):

Since the "submit" button is actually an anchor tag - you'll have to cancel the request via code (anchors don't have a disabled property) - you can always add a disabled style though:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitcommision").click(function() {
        var num11 = $("#ticketcom_$aff_rep_id").val();
        if(num11=='') {
            //Add disabled class?
            return false;
        } else {
            //Submit logic
        }
    });
});
```